# Rails Mobiscroll not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app and I just installed gem 'mobiscroll-rails'.
I got it working in development on my iMac.  But, when I run it on Heroku, I get:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"):
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png] miss
 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png host=www.requestsys.com fwd=70.34.1.156 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=5ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=728
 heroku[nginx]: 70.34.1.156 - - [20/Jan/2013:23:58:46 +0000] "GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "MobileSafari/8536.25 CFNetwork/609 Darwin/13.0.0" www.requestsys.com
app[web.1]: Started GET "/apple-touch-icon.png" for 70.34.1.156 at 2013-01-20 16:58:47 -0700
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/apple-touch-icon.png"):
cache: [GET /apple-touch-icon.png] miss
"GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 728 "-" "MobileSafari/8536.25 CFNetwork/609 Darwin/13.0.0" www.requestsys.com
at=info method=GET path=/apple-touch-icon.png host=www.requestsys.com fwd=70.34.1.156 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=728

My application.html.erb has:

```
  <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
  <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
  <link href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
  <link href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72">
  <link href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114">
```

Thanks!

UPDATE -- now I'm getting this:

ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after ".ios td:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " first-child .d..."
(in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)):
17:       }
18:   
19:
20:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4520300412125467599_68152740'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some invalid CSS somewhere in the mobiscroll-rails gem. I got it locally when I bundled:

```
gem 'mobiscroll-rails'
```

and did `rake assets:precompile`, which is what's happening on Heroku during asset compilation. I loaded the version from the git repo and was able to precompile just fine:

```
gem 'mobiscroll-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/crushlovely/mobiscroll-rails.git'
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you can try this gem that just came out a couple of days ago:

https://github.com/Dinuz/mobiscroll-rails.git

Comment: I'll try the Dinuz version.  Thanks